# Restrict users to their own entities

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

How can we restrict users to their own entities within the Framework? I know that we can check the session Id or include the currentSession in the LINQ query but I kind of wonder if the framework provides a better and efficient way to overcome this?

Comment: "their own entities" - do you mean with regards to multi-tenant support? If so, on the entity you implement `IMayHaveTenant` or `IMustHaveTenant` and let the data filters do their magic. https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#data-filters

Comment: As Reddog says use IMustHaveTenant in your entity. So it is automatically filtered by Tenants

Answer (score 0):

**If multi-tenant support**

Salesforce.com uses the concept of OrganizationId. The downside is that a given email address can't be used in more than 1 organization to log on.

So whenever a user would add a Project or whatever, the record would include their OrganizaionId. Then other users would be limited to only projects that had their OrganizationId.

**If just user created records**

Include a column in your primary tables called "Owner" and populate that with their username.

Comment: What does this question have to do with salesforce.com?

Comment: For more clarification:

Comment: i think salesforce.com is based on the aspnetboilerplate framework. that's why JBrooks wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

I gave an example on the [old forums](https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=20291#p20291) of how to manually create an interface called **IMustOwnEntity** which you add to your entities, and an extension method for **IRepository** which uses the interface to control access.

*Create an empty interface for your domain entities to inherit. Then create an extension method and overload the Update to take the entity and a user Id (which you pass from AbpSession or whatever). The method must check if the entity implements your interface, then check if the passed user is the entity's creator before updating otherwise it just updates the entity as normal. You must decide what to do if the user is not the owner; in my example below I just throw an exception.*

**Interface**

```
public interface IMustOwnEntity
{
}
```

**Extension Class**

```
public static class RepositoryExtensions
{
  public static TEntity Update<TEntity>(this IRepository<TEntity> repository, TEntity entity, long userId) where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>, ICreationAudited
  {
    if (entity is IMustOwnEntity)
    {
      var exists = repository.FirstOrDefaultAsync((record) => record.Id == entity.Id && record.CreatorUserId == userId);

      if (exists != null)
      {
          return repository.Update(entity);
      }
      else
      {
          throw new Exception("Record does not belong to user");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      return repository.Update(entity);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have actually read your response in the old forum and I was thinking of another way of achieving it. Introducing an extended Repository sounds a good idea but has its own downsides. By having an extended Repository I will be limited only to those new methods and miss all the useful existing ones unless I create a like for each method in the base repository. Any chance that I could achieve what I am after through defining a new permission or creating a custom Attribute to be applied on each API method?I mean an Attribute that'd throw an error if entity wasn't for user

Comment: I didn't say create a new repository type, I'm saying create an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). It allows you to "add" methods to an existing type without creating a derived type,

Comment: Hey Andre, Sorry for the late response as I have been away... Your recommended solution makes perfectly sense. But I am wonder if I need to override every single method in the main repository to have the checking included? for instance for a simple GetAll() method I have to include a check to only return entities for the user.Now there are other methods in the main repository like GetAsync... Therefore, I should either override all the methods and have the check included or just override main ones and limit my self with them. Any thought?